# Caffe not reading all h5 files

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I have the following h5 files listed in `train.txt` which I am giving to the hdf5 data layer.

> ```
> /home/foo/data/h5_files/train_data1.h5
> /home/foo/data/h5_files/train_data2.h5
> /home/foo/data/h5_files/train_data3.h5
> /home/foo/data/h5_files/train_data4.h5
> /home/foo/data/h5_files/train_data5.h5
> ```

I have 3 datasets - `X`, `Meta` and `Labels` in these files. Initially, I kept all these in 1 h5 file, but since caffe can't handle h5 files bigger than 2 GB, I had to divide X (say X consists of 5000 samples), in 5 parts. In the first h5, I have Meta and Labels stored along with the first part, i.e; 1000 samples of X, and in the remaining 4 h5 files, I have 1000 samples each. 
   When I start finetuning, caffe crashes with the following error message

```
0111 07:46:54.094041 23981 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer data
 net.cpp:76] Creating Layer data
 net.cpp:334] data -> X
 net.cpp:334] data -> Labels
 net.cpp:334] data -> Meta
 net.cpp:105] Setting up data
 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:66] Loading list of HDF5  filenames from: /home/foo/hdf5_train.txt
 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:80] Number of HDF5 files: 5
 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:53] Check failed: hdf_blobs_[i]->num() == num (5000 vs. 1000) 

*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f1eebcab0d0  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f1eebcab029  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f1eebcaaa07  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f1eebcad98f  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f1ef18ff045  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LoadHDF5FileData()
    @     0x7f1ef18fdca4  caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7f1ef196bffc  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7f1ef196e0b2  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7f1ef18cf3cd  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f1ef18cfa3f  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f1ef18cfe75  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x40a3c8  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x404fb1  train()
    @           0x405936  main
    @       0x3a8141ed1d  (unknown)
    @           0x4048a9  (unknown)
```

The main thing, according to me is 'Check failed: hdf_blobs_[i]->num() == num (5000 vs. 1000)' 
From which I assume that caffe is reading only the first h5 file, how can I make it read all 5 h5 files? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you expect `caffe` synchronize all your input data across all the files? Do you expect it to read `X` from the second file and `Meta` from the first?
If you were to implement `"HDF5Data"` layer, how would *you* expect the data to be laid out for you?

The way things are implemented in caffe at the moment, ALL variables should be divided between the HDF5 files in the same manner. That is if you decided that  `X` will be divided into 5 files, with e.g., 1000 samples in the first file, 1234 samples in the second etc. Then you **must** divide `Meta` and `Labels` in the same manner: `train_data1.h5` will have 1000 samples of `X`, `Meta` and `Label`; `train_data2.h5` will have 1234 samples of `X`, `Meta` and `Label` and so forth.

Caffe does not load all the data into memory, it only fetches the batch it needs for the SGD iteration. Therefore, it makes no sense to split the variables across different files. Moreover, It might help if you make the number of samples stored at each file an integer multiplicity of your `batch_size`.